# Purpose of Interface with no method/constant definition

Tags: java

I am a newbie to Java.
I was able to compile the following interface without any errors.

File Name : `empty_interface.java`

File content :

```
public interface empty_interface {}
```

Questions

a) Interface , i believe, is a contract which the implementor has to implement. What would a implementor will implement if it extends the above interface ?

b) Might be related to a)...but here I go...Why would compiler allow a undefined interface to compile successfully ?

Comment: Note that the naming convention in java would give your interface the name `EmptyInterface` or something like that.

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of "marker" interfaces in the JDK already.  This just signify something which doesn't need methods.

The most common example is Serializable which signifies the class can be serialized.  The library does the rest so no additional methods are required.

An obscure one is RandomAccess which signifies than a List can be accessed randomly in an efficient manner.  The Collections.sort() uses it.

Another class is Cloneable which is a marker interface but probably should have had a method

```
public Object clone();
```

Since Java 5.0, a better way to add meta information like this is to use Annotations, but these were not available previously.

Here is Jon Skeet's excellent answer to a similar question [marker interface in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026557/marker-interface-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

Empty interfaces are marker interfaces, that satisfy multiple roles.

Serialization requires an instance of a class that implements `Serializable`. The only reason the interface exists is to mark out non-serializable classes(and those the dev doesn't care about serialization for) by absence, and to make developers of their own classes think as to whether their class is serializable.

Oddly enough `Serializable` mentions a couple of *optional* methods.

Another hypothetically-valid but not very-useful use is to accept multiple unrelated classes without accepting all said classes.

Comment: To be more precise, it exists to point out serializable classes, not the other way around :) Of course, it does both.

Comment: @Keyser Yes, but by implication classes sans interface are either ignored by the dev in terms of serialization or distinctly unserializable.

Answer (score 1):

The interface isn't undefined, it just has no methods defined for it.

An empty interface typically serves as a flag for whether a class supports some behavior.

Whether this is a good pattern is debated, a good example of this in practice is [Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html), and [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Cloneable lets you know the class implementing it can be cloned via `Object.clone`, while Serializable lets you know the implementing class allows serialization.

I personally see nothing wrong with this.

Comment: Is naming an interface as IFoo somewhat more of a C++ thing, out of curiosity?

Comment: Yeah it is. I've recently taken to naming my interfaces like this though as it helps me find them easier haha...

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll have to try that to help my organization.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure there's debate around whether its good practice, but I personally like it. Its hard to keep file names straight sometimes.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison Yeah well it's only _bad_ practice (according to some) if you can think of a perfect and descriptive name and add an `I` to it for no apparent reason.

Comment: @Keyser To be clear, you support this naming scheme given a perfect descriptive name doesn't exist? I'm personally curious, I've wondered if I'm breaking some clean code rule with this for some time.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison I'm a student with very little real life experience :) But personally, yes, I support it.

Comment: @Keyser haha, ok, thank you for your input anyway. You'll be working one day, your opinion is valid.